# rename microsoft access database in APP_Data folder using ASP.Net - VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i hope this is not a stupid question

i need to rename microsoft access database in APP_Data folder using ASP.Net - VB.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code worked for me without issue.  If the database is in use that might/will cause issues.

```
    Dim mdbpath As String = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/")
    Dim filename As String = "currentName.mdb"
    Dim newFile As String = "newName.mdb"

    System.IO.File.Move(System.IO.Path.Combine(mdbpath, filename), System.IO.Path.Combine(mdbpath, newFile))
```